# React Draft-js Block Insert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, draftjs

**How it Works:**
When the user hits the spacebar the Draft-JS text content is queried for a specific word.  All instances of that word are then wrapped in  tags.  After the text is wrapped the HTML is then converted back and the Draft-JS editor state is updated:

```
      const convertedFromHTML= convertFromHTML(newHTML);
      const editorState = this.state.editorState;

      // Set Editor and Content States
      const newContentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        convertedFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        convertedFromHTML.entityMap
      );

      const nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        newContentState,
        'insert-text'
      );

      this.setState({ 
        editorState: nextEditorState
      });
```

**Block Render Map:**

```
const blockRenderMap = Immutable.Map({
  'Atomic': {
    element: 'Atomic' ,
    wrapper: <GoogleCustomBlock />
  }
});

const myBlockStyleFn = (contentBlock) => {
   const type = contentBlock.getType();
   switch (type) {
     case 'atomic': {
      return 'GoogleCustomBlock';
   }
}
```

**Custom Block Component:**

```
// React Components
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GoogleCustomBlock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='GoogleCustomBlock'>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default GoogleCustomBlock;

**The Issue:** 
This functionality occurs when a user hits the space bar.  The text is wrapped and the correct blocks are added to the DOM.  I am having two difficulties listed below:

- I need to insert a space after the the end of the text.
- The cursor jumps back to the start of the document, but also stays within the new block that was created via the  elements.  I need it to resume editing outside of the new block and at the end of the text.

I have searched online but no luck so far, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: too broad
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.** Also, fix your title so it is descriptive of the question or problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**  Highlighting text and inserting space on space-bar key command:

```
   insertInlineStyles = (editorState, indexes, googleSearchTerm) => {
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
      const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();

      // Loop Through indexes //
      const newSelection = selectionState.merge({
        anchorOffset: index[i],
        focusOffset: googleSearchTerm.length
      })

      // Create new Editor State with Selection on Targeted Word //
      const editorStateWithNewSelection = EditorState.forceSelection(editorState, newSelection);

      // Toggle Inline Style //
      const editorStateWithStyles = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorStateWithNewSelection,'GoogleStyle');

      // Set Selection Back to Previous //
      const editorStateWithStylesAndPreviousSelection = EditorState.forceSelection(
        editorStateWithStyles,
        selectionState
      )

      // Return Editor //
      return editorStateWithStylesAndPreviousSelection;
   }

    /// INSIDE OF ANOTHER FUNCTION

    /// GET INDEX OF WORD TO HIGHLIGHT
    var indexes = [INDEX OF WORD];

    /// INSERT INLINE STYLES
    var newEditorState = this.insertInlineStyles(this.state.editorState, indexes, googleSearchTerm);

    /// ADD SPACE to TEXT
    let newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
      newEditorState.getCurrentContent(), // New content
      currentState.getSelection(), // End of old content selection
      " " // Text to add
    );
    let finalEditorState = EditorState.push(
      newEditorState, 
      newContentState, 
      'insert-characters'
    );

    this.setState({ 
      editorState: finalEditorState 
    });
```